# Can anyone suggest me if i can install pg_dump package in airflow GKC itself? Does GCP allow us to modify prebuild airflow integration with GKC?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, airflow

i have a airflow running on GCP as a composer. I an working on a python peoject where i need to dump a remote postgreSQL database to my airflow bucket but the airflow doesn’t allow me to do so. I am wonder, i can run mysqldump on the same instance to so but my requirement is changed and now i want to do the same on postgresql using pg_dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify the airflow image that runs in Cloud Composer; however, you can use the [KubernetesPodOperator](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-kubernetes-pod-operator) to launch a new pod with pg_dump, execute it and upload the file to Cloud Storage.